# ssh keeps disconnecting when I run multiple tasks using tmux

Tags: networking, ssh, tmux

I have several server machines in my home network. I install tmux on one of them and connecting to it from my laptop. I open multiple panes on 1 tmux window, and anytime that I run some thing too 'heavy' like running apt-get install multiple-packages -y on all servers, the ssh from my laptop to the server is disconnected, and I cannot ssh into it. After some time, the packages were installed, and I can connect to the server with ssh again.

So my questions are:
Is this normal that ssh keeps disconnecting like this? I'm suspecting that this is a network congestion problem. Or it is the tmux receiving all outputs from all server, which kicks me out of ssh?.Or ssh is like second class citizen, so when server needs more bandwidth, it'll terminate ssh for more essential activities? How can I troubleshoot this, and know where this problem comes from? network's not sufficient, or it's server problem. Thanks

Comment: No, this is not normal. How do you debug this? Collect more information, search system logs for anything out of the ordinary, measure network latency using ping and try anything else that would tell you more about your problem.

Comment: If you can't connect using ssh, you can run ssh in verbose `-vvv` mode to see where it fails. Whether it's network or encryption (=> CPU) related.